# Android: What is the best practice to organize methods to show alert dialog

Tags: java, android

I am beginner in Android development. Suppose I have some methods to show `AlertDialog` within an Activity. But each `AlertDialog` behavior is slightly different. What is the best practice to organize the methods to show `AlertDiaolog`?

code is like this.

```
private void showNumberPickerDialog() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    View numberPickerDialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.number_picker, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialog.setTitle("Title for number picker here");
    alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
    alertDialog.setView(numberPickerDialogView);
    final NumberPicker numberPicker = roomSizeNumberDialogView.findViewById(R.id.number_picker);
    numberPicker.setMaxValue(10);
    numberPicker.setMinValue(0);
    numberPicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
             // Something here
                       }
    });
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
          }
    });
    alertDialog.show();        
}


private void showMessageDialog(final boolean isA) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialog.setTitle("Title here");
    alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if (isA) {
                doA();
            } else {
                doB();
            }
        }
    });
    alertDialog.show();
}

private void showAlertDialogC() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    final EditText inputEditText = new EditText(this);
    inputEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    innputEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(10)});
    alertDialog.setTitle("Title here");
    alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
    alertDialog.setView(nameEditText);
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // Do something here
    });
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Is there a good way to organize the parts like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a customizable dialog if that's what you are looking for.

```js
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_options);
dialog.show();
TextView tvDelete = dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvDelete);
tvDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    dialog.dismiss();
    Dialog deleteDialog = new Dialog(context);
    deleteDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_delete);
    deleteDialog.show();
  }
});
```

Treat it just like you would treat an activity. Set onClickListeners on the views for which you want some particular actions. I believe this custom dialog is much more flexible than the `AlertDialog`

Answer (score 0):

I like to handle my dialog in a separate class, that way you have more control over everything - clickListners, layout design, etc... and you don't have tons of code lines in your activity.

**For example, create dialogClass:**

```
public class ProgressDialog extends Dialog {

public ProgressDialog(@NonNull Context context) {
    super(context);

    setContentView(R.layout.progress_dialog); //this is your layout for the dialog

    }
}
```

**And all you need to do is to create dialog instant and call it like this:**

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
progressDialog.show(); // this line shows your dialog
```